# Is the work derivation for torque correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

I am posting [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/597344) for context (see the comments).

I don't think I can be any more eloquent in explaining the derivation in question so I will quote it:

> Consider a point mass, m, mounted on a thin, rigid, mass-less rod with a friction-less axle at one end. The mass is at a distance, r, from the axle. Now push on the rod at a distance, R, from the axle with a force, F, which is normal to the rod and the axle. As the rod swings through an angle, θ, the force does work, F(Rθ), and the rod does work on the mass, (ma)(rθ) = m(rα)(rθ)= (mr2)αθ. Equate the two works and divide by, θ, and you get FR = (mr2)α. Add more forces and more masses and the analysis still applies. (The corresponding quantities of work also add.) Distribute the forces and masses throughout a rigid 3D body and the analysis still applies (with the radii perpendicular to the chosen axis). - R.W. Bird

This derivation clearly argues that conservation of energy would hold because it says that the work done by the force through FRθ should be the same as the mass times the acceleration (ma or mrα) of the mass times the distance that it travels through its arc, rθ.

Firstly, I would disagree with this because I don't think the work done by the force through its arc Rθ is meaningful, as the only actual work it does is on the mass that travels through rθ (for more information see comments of linked answer above).

Furthermore, this explanation would violate conservation of momentum as it says that the same force applied over a given time would cause more or less acceleration depending on where it was applied (for more information see comments of linked answer above).

Lastly, I am emphasizing that I'm am NOT saying that torque is incorrect, only that the work derivation of torque (which I believe is very common) is invalid and that there must be another explanation.

(I have posted the other answer and the comments only because if I were to repeat the entire argument it would take up a lot of space, so I am providing it as an option for those who do not think my summary is detailed enough)

Answer (score 1):

(a) "I don't think the work done by the force through its arc Rθ is meaningful, as the only actual work it does is on the mass that travels through rθ"

Work = Force . Displacement of point of application of force.

That's what's being used here. The system being discussed is really a lever, and $FR\theta$ is the work done by the effort, or, in the language of machines, the work input. I see nothing wrong with equating it to the work output, which, in this case, is used to accelerate *m*.

(b) "this explanation would violate conservation of momentum as it says that the same force applied over a given time would cause more or less acceleration depending on where it was applied"

I'm not sure how your objection works. Conservation of momentum concerns the vector sum of linear momenta of bodies in a system on which no net external force acts. You don't seem to have such a system here.

Comment: But specifically, doesn't work = mad, and even though the force is being applied through Rθ, it is only doing work on the mass at rθ? And could you elaborate on the external forces, because I'm only considering the centripetal force causing the mass to take a circular path, which doesn't affect the magnitude of the momentum, only its direction, is this incorrect?

Comment: (a) "even though the force is being applied through Rθ, it is only doing work on the mass at rθ" Please go back to the definition of work that I quoted. A key phrase is "point of application of force". (b) "the centripetal force causing the mass to take a circular path, which doesn't affect the magnitude of the momentum, only its direction". No, but it causes the momentum to *change* as momentum is a vector. (c) You need to be clear about exactly what system you are applying momentum conservation to, and make sure that the no net external force condition is met.

Comment: Okay, so regarding the work done, I argued that technically wouldn't the force have to be applied at the mass at r since that's the thing it's doing work on (if that makes sense) even though it's said to be applied at R? or I don't think energy should be conserved because I don't see how the same force applied over the same time could do more/less work  on a mass depending on where it is applied (assuming all other forces remain the same). (1/2)

Comment: For momentum, if the magnitude of the momentum remains the same, the angular acceleration of the particle would be (F/m)/(r) which is not equivalent to (FR)/(mr^2) as determined by the work derivation. (2/2)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really follow your last two comments. Let's hope you get other answers.

Comment: For my last comment, if the magnitude of momentum is conserved, only considering the centripetal acceleration of the bearing, The change in momentum equals Ft = mat = mrαt, so F = mrα so α = (F)/(mr). If energy is conserved, as he already showed, α = FR/(mr^2)