# Is the definition of Work done by Torque a general result?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, work, definition, torque

I was going through this [post.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598310/is-the-work-derivation-for-torque-correct)

In the post the person who asked the question mentioned a statement:

> "Lastly, I am emphasizing that I'm am NOT saying that torque is incorrect, only that the work derivation of torque (which I believe is very common) is invalid and that there must be another explanation.Lastly, I am emphasizing that I'm am NOT saying that torque is incorrect, only that the work derivation of torque (which I believe is very common) is invalid and that there must be another explanation."

This got me to wondering. It is very common to find the definition of Work done by Torque in Undergrad books as
$$dW =   \vec \tau . d\vec\theta \tag1$$

However I think that the above definition is only valid or at least useful when the acceleration of centre of mass of a system is zero.

And in case where system's centre of mass has an acceleration, it is better to use the general definition of Work as

$$dW = \vec F . d\vec r \tag2$$

where $d\vec r$ represents the displacement of point of application of force $\vec F$.

However I am unable to understand that if equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are synonymous.

---

Question:

1. Is equation $(1)$ strictly a general result or only applies to certain special cases?
2. Are equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ same?

Comment: why are you making the same statement twice?

Comment: >However I think that the above definition is only valid or at least useful when the acceleration of centre of mass of a system is zero.  Disagree. Consider particle moving in circular motion having tangential accceleration, the center of mass is particle it self and it is accelerating, yet the formula is applicable

Comment: @BobD It has been my personal experience on this forum (maybe due to my writing style) that whenever I include multiple parts in the same question, answerers tend to ignore one or over emphasise the other. Hence I write questions I want to ask separately in the Question section as points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation (1) can be derived from equation (2) by considering $\vec r$ in equation as a differential displacement along the circumference of a circle of radius $R$ (see Fig below) which is given by

$$d\vec r=Rd\vec \theta$$

Then,

$$dW=\vec F.d\vec r$$

becomes

$$dW=R\vec F. d\vec \theta$$

Then, since

$$\vec\tau =R\vec F$$

We have

$$dW=\vec\tau .d\vec\theta$$

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I think the philosophy is that the form of formula is just an artifact of the coordinate system, there is nothing particularly deep about it. For example, I think similar results would hold in spherical coordinates. What do you think?

Comment: @Buraian Hi Buraian.  I agree it is related to the coordinate system but I think there is more to it.  IMO the work done by torque through an angular displacement is fundamentally different than linear displacement from the standpoint that the former can result in a change in rotational KE while the latter can result in a change in translational KE, which are fundamentally different from one another.

Comment: Suppose it was indeed fundamental, then this quantity must exist indifferent to choice of coordinate system. So, take for example that we worked in pure cartesian then, for a particle pushed along a circle along a circle by an external force $\vec{F}$, the work would be $F_x dx + F_y dy= F_x d(Rcos t) + F_y d(R sin t)$ . Further the velocity can be written in terms of the v_x and v_y without reference to any rotations

Comment: Do you agree that rotational KE and translational KE are fundamentally different?

Comment: I understand them as being distinguished by one caused by rotations and other by translations. However, I think this distinction only exists due to the choice of coordinate systems, and hence I don't believe they are fundamentals. I am not very clear on this, maybe there are examples against what I am said, hence I brought up this point.

Comment: OK, then in that case can you give me an example of how rotational KE becomes translational KE  and vice versa by changing coordinate systems?

Comment: @BobD That is what I am talking about. Sir you assumed that the particle is in a circular motion. However, whats the point of defining work done by torque when I can easily use the work done by force in displacing its point of application for the same purpose? In other words, isn't the formula of work done by Torque nothing but a simplification in cases of pure rotation to help us with calculations?

Comment: @TonyStark Just to be clear, when you say "same purpose" do you mean for causing circular motion?

Comment: By "same purpose", I mean for providing energy to the system. What I mainly want to get clarified is that "isn't the formula of work done by Torque nothing but a simplification in cases of pure rotation to help us with calculations?".

Comment: @TonyStark Torque and Force don't serve the same purpose "for providing energy to the system".  You can have different rotational kinetic energies with the same value of force, because force alone doesn't include moment arm and torque does. That's the fundamental difference between them. Regarding your last statement the formula of work done by Torque is not a simplification. If anything, work done by force is the simplification which only applies if the line of action of the force is through the center of mass

Comment: When the line of action of the force is not through the COM (torque) it produces both linear and angular momentum only. If it acts through the COM it produces linear momentum only.  Linear and angular momentum are separate conserved properties, but only torque produces both.

Comment: So should I write Work as Work done by force in displacing centre of mass plus work done by torque in causing angular displacement is Centre of mass frame?

Comment: @TonyStark Assuming you meant "in" the centre of mass frame,  yes.

Comment: The expression for $\vec{\tau} \cdot \hat{d \theta}$ is simply an artifact of the coordinate system. Nothing more, nothing less. I will show what I mean with an example, consider a particle moving in a circle with a velocity $ \vec{v}$ which changes with time due to a force $F= |F| \hat{\theta}$. 

Let us now consider the expression for work in polar coordinates with origin at center of circle. We have the following vector line element, $dl = r d \theta \hat{\theta} + dr \hat{r}$, to get the infinitesiaml work we dot with the force:

$$ dW = |F| r d \theta$$

Comment: Now, observe that $r|F|$ coincides with the expression for torque on that particle, hence we could rewrite the work as:

$$ dW= \vec{\tau} \cdot d \theta \hat{\theta}$$

Ok this looks nice, and seems deep but if it is truly a fundamental fact, then it must be that it should come in another parameterization as well.

Comment: Let's check by taking the cartesian line element $dl = dx \hat{i} + dy \hat{j}$ then in this case our work becomes:

$$ dW = |F| \hat{\theta} \cdot ( dx \hat{i} + dy \hat{j})$$

Recall that $\hat{\theta} = - \sin \theta \hat{i} + \cos \theta \hat{j}$, this leads to:

$$ dW= |F| (- \sin \theta dx + \cos \theta dy)$$

Let's take our path is given as a circle with radius $R$ i.e: $ y= \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, and we go  from $(0,R)$ to $(R,0)$:

Comment: ..
and at this point I realized bob D is right because no matter how you parameterize it, it coincides with the torque equation GG

Comment: Sorry for series of comments, I had written this as an answer, only at end did I realize it.  Apologies for my initial ignorance. The torque angular energy thing is fundamentally different as you have said Bob.

Comment: @Buraian No problem. It's always best to reach the conclusion yourself.